# How to make css3 animations work in outlook 2013?

Tags: css, email, outlook-2013

I want to add some CSS3 animations to my signature in outlook but the animation is not rendering. How to make css3 animations work in outlook 2013?

Comment: Did you try something? Like taking a working example (working in a browser https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/ ), pasting it in an email that you send to yourself?

Comment: Hmm.. good idea.. I will try first

Comment: I tried . But its not working

Answer (score 0):

Signatures are part of the email when sent, they are very restrictive on different part of hte code that they accept, also they may render different in different email clients/browsers, so as per policy, you should keep the signature relatively simple.

Another thing to take in consideration is that they won't accept or work well with stylesheets but inline style properties. so every object of your html should have their css properties inline (that may get your animation working, but for email client restirctions I still doubt it will)